# JTextArea always null?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jtextarea

This is my  code, which is pretty simple, it is just creating a `JFrame` with a `JTextArea` in the centre.

`if(!txtSource.getText().trim().equals("") && txtSource != null)`

is never satisfied even when I have entered text into the JTextArea.

I only want to execute methodA() if the JTextArea has some text.

```
private Container content;
private JTextArea txtSource;

public Test() {
    this.setTitle("Test");
    this.setSize(600,200);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    content = this.getContentPane();
    content.add(getTextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    content.add(button(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.setVisible(true); 
}

private JTextArea getTextArea() {
    JTextArea txtSource = new JTextArea(20, 80);
    return txtSource;
}

private JButton button() {

    JButton btn = new JButton("Click me");

    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             if(!txtSource.getText().trim().equals("") && txtSource != null) {
                 methodA();
             } else { 
                 System.out.println("Please paste your script in.");
         }
    }
}
```

Please help me here...

Comment: `txtSource != null` better be on the left side.

Comment: When I enter some text in, it still just executes `System.out.println("Please paste your script in.");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're [shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) the `txtSource` variable, replace

```
JTextArea txtSource = new JTextArea(20, 80);
```

with

```
txtSource = new JTextArea(20, 80);
```

Comment: What he means by "shadowing" is that by re-declaring your txtSource variable inside of a constructor or method, and then initializing the re-declared variable, you are initailizing a variable whose scope is limited to the method or constructor and will leave the class field null. The solution, as he shows, is to not re-declare the variable inside of a method or constructor. Sure go ahead and initialize the variable there, but do so on the class field, not on a local variable. 1+

Comment: Link added to explain shadowing

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels or simply "hiding a field"

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you never initialize `txtSource`. Sure you declare it, but just because `getTextArea()`'s return value is called`txtSource` doesn't assign the class variable as such.

In the `test()` method you should assign `this.txtSource` as `getTextArea()` and then add that to the container.